# Ansible: How to use regular and encrypted variables from dictionaries in group_vars?

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I am trying to split my group_vars into unencrypted "vars" and encrypted "vault". As the official documentation is quite short, I followed a very thorough tutorial given [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-vault-to-protect-sensitive-ansible-data-on-ubuntu-16-04#using-vault-encrypted-variables-with-regular-variables). With their example setup I can make it work. The vars file references vaulted parts like so:

```
mysql_port: 3306
mysql_host: 10.0.0.3
mysql_user: fred
mysql_password: "{{ vault_mysql_password }}"
```

Now my real use case has dictionaries in those files like this:

```
---
vhosts:
    vhost1:
      mysql_user: fred
      mysql_password: "{{ vault_mysql_password }}"
    vhost2:
      mysql_user: frida
      mysql_password: "{{ vault_mysql_password }}"
```

My vault file is organized in a similar way and that's what doesn't work out:

```
---
vhosts:
    vhost1:
      vault_mysql_password: secret1
    vhost2:
      vault_mysql_password: secret2
```

The result that I get is: Ansible does find all *encrypted* variables. But it claims the *regular* ones are undefined. Here is the output of the debug command where mysql_user is missing from the debug output:

```
ansible --ask-vault-pass -m debug -a 'var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]' database
Vault password: 
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname]": {
        "ansible_check_mode": false, 
        "ansible_connection": "local", 
        "ansible_playbook_python": "/usr/bin/python", 
        "ansible_version": {
            "full": "2.4.1.0", 
            "major": 2, 
            "minor": 4, 
            "revision": 1, 
            "string": "2.4.1.0"
        }, 
        "group_names": [
            "database"
        ], 
        "groups": {
            "all": [
                "localhost"
            ], 
            "database": [
                "localhost"
            ], 
            "ungrouped": []
        }, 
        "inventory_dir": "/home/user/ansible/vault-test", 
        "inventory_file": "/home/user/ansible/vault-test/hosts", 
        "inventory_hostname": "localhost", 
        "inventory_hostname_short": "localhost", 
        "omit": "__omit_place_holder__2aa3b7d59a4009e07f27cf11ffabda560533de17", 
        "playbook_dir": "/home/user/ansible/vault-test", 
        "vhosts": {
            "vhost1": {
                "vault_mysql_password": "secret1"
            }, 
            "vhost2": {
                "vault_mysql_password": "secret2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any hints what I have to do are greatly appreciated! Or am I trying to do an impossible thing?

Comment: can you please share your test playbook and the directory structure you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encrypted vars behave same ways as unencrypted ones. And in your case you just overwrite `vhosts` var from plain vars file with `vhosts` from vaulted one.

This will work:

```
---
vhosts:
    vhost1:
      mysql_user: fred
      mysql_password: "{{ vault_vhosts.host1.vault_mysql_password }}"
    vhost2:
      mysql_user: frida
      mysql_password: "{{ vault_vhosts.host2.vault_mysql_password }}"

---
vault_vhosts:
    vhost1:
      vault_mysql_password: secret1
    vhost2:
      vault_mysql_password: secret2
```

Or this:

```
---
vhosts:
    vhost1:
      mysql_user: fred
      mysql_password: "{{ vault_vhost1_mysql_password }}"
    vhost2:
      mysql_user: frida
      mysql_password: "{{ vault_vhost2_mysql_password }}"

---
vault_vhost1_mysql_password: secret1
vault_vhost2_mysql_password: secret2
```

Comment: Yes! That's working, I understand! Thanks a lot, Konstantin!